# Why I am getting `Endpoint request timed out` error when AWS SecretsManager is implemented?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a REST API with AWS Lambda, API Gateway, RDS (MySQL). I am using Node.js.

This is my normal AWS Lambda code, calling database table to get the data and send it over the REST API.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : "****.****.****.rds.amazonaws.com",
  user     : "****",
  password : "****",
  port     : 3306,
  database : "****"
});

exports.getAllRoles = (event, context, callback) => {
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const sql = "select * from role";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(result),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    callback(null, response)
  });
};
```

This is the same code, but now with `AWS SecretsManager`

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


// Load the AWS SDK
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    region = "us-east-1",
    secretName = "test-secret",
    secret,
    decodedBinarySecret;

// Create a Secrets Manager client
var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region
});


exports.getAllRoles = (event, context, callback) => {

    client.getSecretValue({
        SecretId: secretName
    }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
            // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
            if ('SecretString' in data) {
                secret = data.SecretString;
            } else {
                let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
            }
        }
        // Your code goes here. 
        const secretObj = JSON.parse(secret);

        //Create MySQL Connection
        const con = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : secretObj.host,
            user     : secretObj.user,
            password : secretObj.password,
            port     : secretObj.port,
            database : secretObj.database
          });

        // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        const sql = "select * from role";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var response = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "body": JSON.stringify(result),
                "isBase64Encoded": false
            };
            callback(null, response)
        });
    });    

};
```

This is my cloud formation file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aaaa-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aaaa-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 100
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-4424242424
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-424242424242

Resources:
  
  GetAllRolesFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aaaa-restapi/
      Handler: role-getall.getAllRoles
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /role/getall
            Method: get
  

  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'
```

My code without the `AWS SecretsManager` is working fine when deployed.

However the code with `AWS SecretsManager` is giving `timeout error` when deployed and tested the API Call with `POSTMAN`. I just call

`https://*****.****-api.****-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/role/getall`

I just see `"message": "Endpoint request timed out"` and nothing else, even in the console. The same code is working fine when executed with `sam invoke local GetAllRolesFunction`. Also fine when tested with `sam local start-api`. The issue only arises when uploaded to AWS and the API Call is made.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message "Endpoint request timed out" from API Gateway suggests that your API-invoked Lambda function  took longer than 29 seconds to complete.

I am going to guess that your Lambda function is running in a VPC and you have correctly set up network routing to your (private) RDS database but you don't have a network route to the Secrets Manager service endpoint, hence that request times out. If so, you'd need a [VPC Endpoint for Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html) or a NAT (or NAT Gateway) with routing to the public internet.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The database is `public` but access is controlled with `Security Groups`. Does this make any modifications to your answer?

Comment: Plus, can you guide me to implement the VPC with CloudFormation I have?

Comment: Does the Lambda function run in a VPC? If so, is it configured to run in in a private subnet? Does that subnet have a default route to NAT?

Comment: Yes a VPC is attached to the Lambda Function. The VPCs are working with multiple subnets, I'm really not sure whether they are private. When I was creating the RDS it auto assigned few subnets and the same subnets are used by the Lambda. No IDEA about the NAT.. everything assigned with lambda you can see in my yaml file above, because I didn't manually create anything rather than the RDS and the subnets that it assigned itself.

Comment: You supplied the VPC subnet ID so the VPC already exists. If you created the VPC then I presume that you know what its configuration is, or at least how to determine that. If someone else provided it to you then they can help you understand whether or not it has NAT and whether or not the correct routing is in place for your Lambda to reach the Secrets Manager endpoint via the public internet or via a VPC endpoint.